# Problem with access private uint in a contract

Tags: solidity, web3js, storage

I want to access a private data in a smart contract, I know that it is located in the second slot, and I use this code :

```
await web3.eth.getStorageAt('0xeB51Bceb2F930aC619815E96FfB8E57C84Fb67Cd' , 1)
```

but i get this error :

```
Uncaught (in promise) Error: Internal JSON-RPC error.
{
  "message": "Upgrade to an archive plan add-on for your account. Max height of block allowed on archive for your current plan: 128",
  "code": -32005
}
```

I would appreciate it if you could explain the reason and solution to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an RPC limit error. This means whatever product you are using is not allowing you access to the blockchain.

**Explanation**: RPC providers basically run their nodes and provide API to us, so that we can interact with the blockchain without running our own node.

**Solution** : Either you upgrade your plan on whatever provider you are using, or use a different one. There are many free providers. Like [Alchemy](https://www.alchemy.com/), [Quicknode](https://www.quicknode.com/) etc.

Comment: Thank you, I actually used the firefox console to do it and it has this problem, and the video tutorial worked out the same way.